# Manually calculate probabilities from XGBoost model in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, data-science, xgboost

I am trying to manually calculate probabilities from `XGBoost` model. Can somebody help me with the formula so that I can replicate.

Work done so far:

1. Extracted weights from `model.best_estimator_.feature_importances_.`
2. Multiplied the weights with respective features and added to arrive at a value.
3. `1 / float(1 + np.exp(value))` to find the predicted probability.

This doesn't seem to be working as the predicted probability from the above method is very different from the probability from `predict_proba`(2.767918e-07 and 0.321 respectively).

FYI, there are both numerical and categorical features in the data.

I am still learning so please feel free correct the above method or suggest the right one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The weights from `model.best_estimator_.feature_importances_` are global feature importance across all trees.
What you need is:

1. traverse the sample down to the leaf nodes of each tree using `model.predict(X,pred_leaf=True)`, you will get n_estimators's leaf nodes.
2. add those leaf nodes weight(you can get this weight from `model._Booster.trees_to_dataframe()`
   [image]
3. apply sigmoid on the weights sum.